# Verifying that measured time does fit O(n^3)

Tags: regression, self-study

I'm dealing with a homework.

We were given a software, with inputs, that we should measure and then verify that the time complexity is O(n^3).

I measured the software, picked best times from each batch (since that's the least affected one), and ended up with this:

```
304   70000
574   480000
775   1190000
850   1580000
1070  3130000
1557  9740000
1965  19540000
```

Now I'm really lost. I know how to calculate a model using least squares, but I have no idea how to do that for O(n^3). Plus I don't know how I would verify that the model is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to get cubic root of this data and see if the transformed data shows linear dependence; seems so:

[image]

If you want to do this the right way, use nonlinear fitting tool like `nls` in R to fit $b \text{time}^a$:

```
> nls(V2~b*V1^a,data=s,start=list(b=1,a=3))
Nonlinear regression model
  model:  V2 ~ b * V1^a 
   data:  s 
       b        a 
0.002525 3.002639 
 residual sum-of-squares: 1.036e+09

Number of iterations to convergence: 4 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.658e-07
```

`summary` method will show you significance of parameters;

```
> summary(nls(V2~b*V1^a,data=s,start=list(b=1,a=3)))

Formula: V2 ~ b * V1^a

Parameters:
   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
b 2.525e-03  8.605e-05   29.35 8.61e-07 ***
a 3.003e+00  4.531e-03  662.64 1.49e-13 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 14400 on 5 degrees of freedom

Number of iterations to convergence: 4 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.658e-07
```

it shows $O(n^3)$ hypothesis is highly supported.

Comment: Wow, that's just an awesome answer. The linear dependence should be enough for me :)

Comment: You are in some sense lucky that the cubic behaviour has already started at the beginning of your data set. If the actual execution time of the function would be approximately $10^{-3}n^3+1000n+10^6$, perfectly $O(n^3)$ behaviour that even shows up with the given inputs, then the R code above would not like the hypothesis much - for $n<1000$, the constant and linear terms dominate the $n^3$ term. Fitting to $an^b$ returns $29n^{1.7}$ with large residual square error. Not sure what would be an easy approach that would work for such data...

Comment: @ErikP Obviously; however when 'measuring' big-O one usually uses sizes that go near asymptotic behavior. In general, nonlinear fitting should always start with plotting data in order to sketch the function that will be used.

Comment: An alternative producing a similar result is to use ordinary linear regression methods on the logarithms of the data: `lm(log(V2) ~ log(V1))`